# What font is used in Adobe CC program icons?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-identification, cs6, creative-cloud

I am looking to create a logo similar to this one, found as the cover image to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5jOg2iDPeM) video:

[image]

But I am having trouble finding a suitable font.  What font is used in the icons for Adobe CC programs?  Are there other sans-serif fonts available in Typekit similar to Futura Bold that are suitable for a logo like the one shown?

Comment: The font used to be Adobe Clean, not sure if that's still the case. If so, it's not available for download/purchase. It's an Adobe font for their use only.

Answer (score 2):

[Phoenica Std](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/preusstype/phoenica/) via myfont.com is a very similar one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A free alternative that I have used in an Adobe Illustrator interface file is **Source Sans Pro**. It's available [from Google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro).